# Proof for how the drift estimator, for a random walk with drift, is unbiased?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, estimators, random-walk

Random walk with drift formula is:
(Yt = α + Yt-1 + εt )

How do I go about checking that the drift estimator α-hat is unbiased.. which is proving that E(α-hat) = α?

Is this something I would need strong mathematics background to understand? It seems to be that I cannot find much information about it online.

Comment: Please give out the $\hat \alpha$, otherwise, no one knows biased or unbiased.

Comment: @user158565 I'm not entirely sure what you mean, I wasn't given a dataset to worth with - just the exact question I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

$\triangle y_{t} = \alpha + \epsilon_{t}$

$E(\triangle y_{t}) = \alpha \rightarrow \hat{\alpha} = \bar{(\triangle y}_{t}) =  \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{n}\triangle y_{t}}{n}$

and it' straightforward to show that $\hat{\alpha}$ is unbiased.